# WCF Message Inspector

Tags: c#, wcf

I need to sign xml reply from service based on WCF

Here is sample code:

```
public void BeforeSendReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateTextWriter(ms, Encoding.UTF8);
            reply.WriteMessage(writer);
            writer.Flush();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(ms);
            doc.Save(@"C:\reply.xml");
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            CspParameters cspParams = new CspParameters();
            cspParams.KeyContainerName = "XML_DSIG_RSA_KEY";    

            RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);
            signedXml.SigningKey = rsaKey;

            Reference reference = new Reference();
            reference.Uri = string.Empty;

            XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform env = new XmlDsigEnvelopedSignatureTransform();
            reference.AddTransform(env);

            signedXml.AddReference(reference);

            signedXml.ComputeSignature();

            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();

            doc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(doc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));

            doc.Save(@"C:\signed_reply.xml");

            MemoryStream signedStream = new MemoryStream();
            doc.Save(signedStream);
            signedStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(signedStream);
            Message newMessage = Message.CreateMessage(reader, int.MaxValue, reply.Version);
            newMessage.Properties.CopyProperties(reply.Properties);
            reply = newMessage;
        }
```

When testing with SoapUI I see nothing and generated client fails on exception. When returning from variable ms everything goes as expected. What can be wrong in this code?

reply.xml

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITest/GetProductResponse</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetProductResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetProductResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebJsonService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Description>test</a:Description>
        <a:Id>5</a:Id>
        <a:Name>test</a:Name>
        <a:Price>0.25</a:Price>
      </GetProductResult>
    </GetProductResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

signed_reply.xml

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header>
    <Action s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://tempuri.org/ITest/GetProductResponse</Action>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetProductResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetProductResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WebJsonService" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <a:Description>test</a:Description>
        <a:Id>5</a:Id>
        <a:Name>test</a:Name>
        <a:Price>0.25</a:Price>
      </GetProductResult>
    </GetProductResponse>
  </s:Body>
  <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
      <CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
      <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
      <Reference URI="">
        <Transforms>
          <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
        </Transforms>
        <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
        <DigestValue>fXEwGkEaeFkpQaxZr1T61l0q5XE=</DigestValue>
      </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>eikY2sH9l12SyEiCwuEKBTqJZjKnkHND/8opBOp3uF0jkR/iYsAxFhDNuVXAghVsTbdllg+G8a/UKMN10JByvl5RV9wULM+5CLKQ2e1d3+0kBZdd5Q568yJNQhYbFENzJP2aRJiv9rWN8ji4QGdDITNy7IVcgv5M8flPr+5/9A8=</SignatureValue>
  </Signature>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: wondering why you need to sign a reply with in service logic, wcf message security does the sign the message ....

Answer (score 1):

Probably the better option would be to use security services provided by WCF itself. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789011.aspx

Comment: I need to sign with gost algorithm